# IText exited editing in chrome forces a page scroll

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fabricjs

I've created a custom IText object sitting on top of a Rectangle that I use for a custom sized/animated entry block. There is a 'changed' listener for the text so that when it reaches a pre-set number of characters typed an `exitEditing()` command is fired.

When this command is fired it forces Chrome to scroll to the bottom of the page. I've tried to confirm that there isn't any hidden text areas from the IText positioned very low and I certainly don't see any, but I'm at a loss for what would be causing this.

The bit of script on fabricjs that is causing the problem seems to be this removeChild:

```
this.canvas && this.hiddenTextarea.parentNode.removeChild(this.hiddenTextarea);
```

Any ideas on how to work around this issue?

Thanks, 
Jason

Comment: on what version of fabricjs are you?

Comment: I am using 1.7.17

Comment: I 'solved' this by changing the line in fabricJS:
`fabric.document.body.appendChild(this.hiddenTextarea);`
to
`fabric.document.body.prepend(this.hiddenTextarea);`

This isn't a perfect solution since it still causes an odd scroll (this time to the top with the prepend) but at least my content is at the top.